# Variable pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to create a C script, which has a variable pointer for example:

```
int main(void){
 double x = 0;
 do{
  x+=1;
  fprint("%d \n",x)
}while{x<100}
}
```

But I want x to be the pointer and that every value that x takes to be written at a certain file.

I think theres 2 things to do, although I don't know how to do them properly:

1. asign memory to the pointer.
2. create the file and append on it.

Comment: It's not clear from your post what your real objective is, i.e. what's the real problem you are trying to solve, and where you need help.

Comment: I am trying to understand pointers by creating such script, I must end up having a file with numbers from 1 to 99 but each entry in the file was written by the variable pointer rather than just printed on it

Comment: I suggest work through examples in a text book, or work through an online tutorial such as the one at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're asking for, but perhaps this could help you. Here `x` is a pointer to `y` and the program increments y in the loop and dereferences the pointer `x` and writes its current value to a file. Of course you wouldn't need a pointer at all to do this, it's just meant as an example.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int y = 0;
  // x points to variable y
  int* x = &y;
  FILE* fout = fopen("output.txt", "w");
  do {
    // dereference x and write value to file
    fprintf(fout, "%d\n", *x);
    // increment y
    y++;
  // dereference pointer x and check if value less than 100
  } while(*x < 100);
  fclose(fout);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was going to make him figure out the file I/O on his own, since this is obviously homework.

Comment: @Cyclone - I would do that, but upvoting requires 15 reputation which I apparently don't have yet and also I don't know how to mark it as correct, I am relatively new to the site.

Comment: @Cyclone I think I got it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first of all you have not declared a single pointer in that code.

A pointer in C is declared as:

[valid type] * [ variable name ] eg:

```
double * age ;
```

This creates a pointer definition for double, but allocates no memory in the heap.  To initialize the pointer you must allocate some memory and you have to tell the compiler how much, eg:

```
age = malloc(sizeof(double)) ;
```

Thats gets you enough memory space to store exactly one double value, *no matter what the actual size of a a double is on the system you are building this on!*

in your code you must dereference the pointer before you try and increment it, eg:

```
*age++;
```

The asterisk before the variable name tells the compiler to give you access to the actual data, and ++ can do its job.  If you do not dereference you are tempting, at best data corruption or at worst you could crash the system.

So your code should look something like so:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){

double * x ;
x = malloc(sizeof(double));

*x = 0

do{
*x++;
  fprint("%d \n",*x)
}while{x* < 100}

}
```

Comment: When you do x = malloc(sizeof(x)); are you aasigning x with empty space equal to the size of a double?

Comment: `x = malloc(sizeof(x))` - that can't be right. `x` is of pointer type, so `sizeof(x)` may be different than `sizeof(double)`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `x = malloc(sizeof(*x));`

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for catching that!